# Is Array.push() mutating the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing:

```
  const array = []

  ...
  array.push({x, y})
```

Is that considered a bad practise. Should I use let or spread the array because "push" is considered a mutating action. It is working though.

Comment: Depends - do you want to *avoid* mutating the array? Note that a mutation is not bad by itself, depends on your use case.

Comment: I'm exaggerating, but it's like asking "is it OK to add two numbers or should I multiply them?". It really depends on how you want/need from the result.

Comment: I don't understand the question, are you unsure about what does _mutate_ means? (the title implies you seems unsure about that, but the body is a bit different)

Comment: *"Should I use let"*. Are you under the impression that you are not allowed `push` to arrays defined with `const`? You are NOT allowed to reassign the variables with `const` like `array = [1,2]`. You are allowed to mutate the arrays and objects by changing their properties. Like `const a = {}` and `a.key1 = 'value'` is allowed. But, `a = { key2: 'value 2 '}` is not allowed

Comment: Its exactly that usecase. An array to wich I push an object.
I can see now that mutating the array is usually not a problem and can be done with const.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is Array.push() mutating the array?

Yes

> Is that considered a bad practise. Should I use let or spread the array because "push" is considered a mutating action.

**Generally** not.

There are times when treating data as immutable is useful, or even essential (such as when you are updating a Redux store).

In those cases, `push` still isn't a bad idea, you just shouldn't do it to your original array.

For example, this is fine and has no side effects:

```
function functionalFunction(input) {
    const output = [...input];
    output.push({x, y});
    // A bunch of other operations that mutate the array go here
    // Be careful not to mutate any objects in the array
    return output;
}
```